# How do I make people admin?

Tags: garrys-mod

I am hosting a gmod server via SteamCMD and I want to know how to make people . Are there any other commands / things I should know about? I know the srcd.exe has all kind of commands but they aren't really usefull. My main objective is to find out how to do the usual things, like ban / kick / make someone admin. How do I do this with the dedicated server with Steamcmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this question still is valid:

Garry's mod has no permission management by default. You will need a plugin / addon for this.
There are several plugins you can use for permission management in Garry's mod.

One of the best out there in my opinion is the ULX mod.
You can find a tutorial on how to install and configure it here:
http://gmod.gamebanana.com/tuts/11079